# i have to get 2 tables data but 2 table columns data in 1 column with comma

Tags: sql-server-2014-localdb

i have use this code to get data from 2 tables

```
SELECT t1.HId,commands=STUFF(   
 (   
   SELECT DISTINCT ',' + t2.commands  
   FROM history_detail t2
   WHERE  t1.HId = t2.History_HID    
   FOR XML PATH('')   
 ),1,1,'') FROM history t1,  history_detail t2  GROUP BY HId
```

but i got this in 2 column with extra data

```
Send("this is your first testcase")&#x0D;,Sleep(3000)&#x0D;,WinActive("notepad")&#x0D;,WinClose("notepad")&#x0D;,WinWaitActive("notepad")&#x0D;
```

i have to remove this `&#x0D;` from the data

Comment: `FROM history, history_detail` is a cross join.  Do you really intend to do this?  Some sample data would help to explain your question.

Comment: above data is the data of 2 column. i want just send("......") not the `&#x0D;` i have to remove it from all data where ever it is coming with column data in it